# Can we automate Apple App Store Connect app update with "Whats New" localization?

Tags: flutter, app-store-connect, fastlane

I have my app in multiple languages and the UI requires translated versions of "Whats New" which is a lot of clicking. Can we include perhaps a release notes in the IPA to get the whats new section prefilled?
I was looking at Fastlane that seems to handle this: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/17318

[image: Apple App Store Connect Whats New Localization]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked this one

```
      upload_to_testflight(
    beta_app_review_info: {
      contact_email: "email@email.com",
      contact_first_name: "Connect",
      contact_last_name: "API",
      contact_phone: "5558675309",
      demo_account_name: "demo@email.com",
      demo_account_password: "connectapi",
      notes: "this is review note for the reviewer <3 thank you for reviewing"
    },
    localized_app_info: {
      "default": {
        feedback_email: "default@email.com",
        marketing_url: "https://example.com/marketing-defafult",
        privacy_policy_url: "https://example.com/privacy-defafult",
        description: "Default description",
      },
      "en-GB": {
        feedback_email: "en-gb@email.com",
        marketing_url: "https://example.com/marketing-en-gb",
        privacy_policy_url: "https://example.com/privacy-en-gb",
        description: "en-gb description",
      }
    },
    localized_build_info: {
      "default": {
        whats_new: "Default changelog",
      },
      "en-GB": {
        whats_new: "en-gb changelog",
      }
    }
  )
```

For reference: [https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/#:~:text=a%20log%22%0A](https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions/testflight/#:%7E:text=a%20log%22%0A))-,upload_to_testflight,-(%0A%20%20beta_app_review_info%3A

Comment: very nice, thank you